# setting state with useState affects all useState hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to build an ecommerce website, and I hit a problem I cannot seem to resolve. I am very new to react and JS so have some patience please :)

I declared 4 useStates in my app.js:

```
const [elementeDinState, setElementeDinState] = useState([]);
const [currentCategorie, setCurrentCategorie] = useState("Acasa");
const [subCategorie, setSubcategorie] = useState([]);
const [cartContents, setCartContents] = useState([]);

const fetchData = useCallback(async () => {
    const data = await getCategories();
    setElementeDinState(data);
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData().catch(console.error);
  }, [fetchData]);

const changeHeader = (dataFromMenuItem) => {
    setCurrentCategorie(dataFromMenuItem);
  };

const changeCopiiContent = (data1FromThere) => {
    setSubcategorie(data1FromThere);
  };

const changeCart = (dataFromCart) => {
    setCartContents(dataFromCart);
  };
```

I am passing the functions to change those states to different child components as props. my problem is, when I add items to cart it triggers a re render of my component (products listing component) that should not be affected by cartContents and that resets the state of said component to the initial value that changes the items being shown. does useState hook create a single global state comprised of all those states?

Comment: Define state like this `const [state,setState]={
 elementeDinState:[],
 currentCategorie:"Acasa",
subCategorie:[],
cartContents:[]
}`
while setting specific value for example then do it like
setState({...state,currentCategorie:"Test"})

Comment: I tired but I'm getting a intermediate value is not iterable setstate

Comment: sorry I missed useState
`useState({elementeDinState:[],  currentCategorie:"Acasa", subCategorie:[], cartContents:[] })`

Comment: well, it does look better now, the code i mean, but the same problem happens. thank you anyway

Comment: can you share your code ?? code sandbox

Comment: I will, right now I'm trying to find another way of updating the cart contents without using a state management library.

Answer (score 1):

If these `useState` are defined in the `app.js` and then passed down, when a child will use them chasing the state will happen in the `app.js` so all the children of `<App />` will be re-rendered.

I guess that your `app.js` looks similar:

```
function App() {
const [elementeDinState, setElementeDinState] = useState([]);
 // ...and the other hooks and methods

return (
   <cartContents setElementDinState={setElementeDinState} />
   <ProductList />
)
}
```

In this case the state is in the  component so when `<CartContents />` changes it, it will trigger a re-render of the  and all its children `<ProductList />` included.

To avoid this problem think better when each piece of state needs to be and put the state as near as possibile to that component. For example, if the state of the cart does not influence the Product list. Move the `useState` in the `<Cart />` component.

Comment: If I don't hold the state in the app.js I cannot access refresh cart contents when I add items to cart. Right now my cart contents live in a Mongo dB and I grab them from there whenever an items is added or removed. Can I update Cart contents from the product component if I don't use a common state? As they are siblings

Comment: This is exactly how React works, and why to handle complex scenarios state management libs are often paired with vanilla react (Redux is most famous probably, but I prefer something simpler like https://github.com/pmndrs/valtio). The first step is to wrap the product list in `useMemo`, this will prevent re-rendering if not needed (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo). My suggestion is to ignore the "re-render" until they are real performance problem.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, your problem is that you're simply resetting the `cartContents` state every time you call the `changeCart` function, correct?

What you probably want, is to *add* (or *remove* ?) the item to the cart, like this?

```
const changeCart = (dataFromCart) => {
  setCartContents(oldContents => [...oldContents, dataFromCart]);
};
```

Comment: the problem is that my productsComponent si getting re rendered when cartContents changes. when my productsComponent is re rendered its state defaults to its initial state and that is not the behavior that I'm expecting

Comment: @Dragos what's the `productsComponent`? You've never mentioned it. Is it the component that contains the 4 states that you've mentioned or is it some sibling component?

Comment: The 4 states are kept in the parent - app.js.productComponet displayed the selected products and the categories

Comment: The 4 states are kept in the parent - app.js. productComponet displayed the selected products and the categories using the state from app.js. The cart component updated the state in app.js and it was refreshing my productComponent reseting the category selected and refetching data from database. I moved the state of product Component in the app.js file and it works ok now

Answer (score 0):

Here is a description of useState from the [oficial site](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html):

> useState is a Hook (...). We call it inside a function component to add some local state to it

So it creates just a local state.

About your problem, We need more information, but I believe that some parent component of that widget is trying to render other component instead of your the component that you wanted (let's call it "ProblemComponent") and rendering you ProblemComponent from scratch again, before you can see it.

it's something like that:

```js
function ParentComponent(props: any) {
    const isLoading = useState(false);
    // Some logic...
       
   if(isLoading) {
       return <LoadingComponent/>;
   }
   
   return <ProblemComponent/>;
}
```

If that doesn't work you can also try to use `React.memo()` to prevent the ProblemComponent to update when it props change.

Answer (score 0):

well, seems like I wanted to change the way react works so I figured out a work around, based on what you guys told me. I declared the state of the productsComponent in the parent component and adding to cart now doesn't force a refresh of the items being shown. thank you!